# Calculating the sum of squared within cluster distances in Matlab

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, linear-algebra

I would like to calculate the "the sum of pair-wise distance between all maps of a given cluster" ([Murray et al., 2008](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10548-008-0054-5)), to further calculate the Krzanowski-Lai criterion in Matlab (MATLAB 2022b). In [Murray et al. (2008)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10548-008-0054-5) the following equation is given for the sum of (squared) distances:

[image: formula]

*u* is a specific the measured values of one time point (one observation, in my case the measured potentials, since I am working with EEG data).
*v* is a specific the measured values of another time point then in *u*.

I found a code, which already implemented the Krzanowski-Lai criterion for my specific data. Thereby, the squared sum of within distances are calculated as following:

```
    Nk = size(cluster,2);
    clstrsq = dot(cluster,cluster,1);
    %sum of pair-wise distance between all maps of cluster k
    Dk = sum(sum(bsxfun(@plus,clstrsq',clstrsq)-2*(cluster'*cluster)));
```

`Cluster` is a vector containing the data for a specific cluster. Columns corresponds to observations, rows to variables. For example, if I have 100 observations and for each observation 10 variables:

```
    cluster = randn(10,100)
```

I have got no good training in linear algebra and math, thus I have got some questions about the implementation.
First, what kind of distance is calculated here.
Second, I do not understand how this code relates to the formula given above. Can some confirm, that this code corresponds to the formula and explain me the deviration?

Comment: So you asking someone else to do the math for you, claiming that you are not good in math. I mean there are at least two ways to solve the issue for yourself. A) You implement it yourself and compare the results between your implementation and the one you found or B) The math isnt as hard as you think. You try to remember the 2nd binomial formula from school and do the math for a very small example (like a cluster of three vectors). Either way you learn this way more than letting someone else do it for you.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the 2nd binomial formula. I would not have found this connection and guessed that it was so simple.